# CollectionPage or OfferCatalog Schema for specific items on a category page for E commerce website

Tags: javascript, product, schema.org

If I have a category page that has a list of links to the specific items, what markup should I be using a CollectionPage or OfferCatalog schema? I know OfferCatalog is offered by the same provider. The site is an e-commerce site that offers different products from different providers. if non of these which markup I should be using? please help I suggested that we can markup Product Schema on an individual level that way in can show up on a category level maybe! Your answers would be really helpful.

The following is the example I have for the collection page.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
 {
     "@context": "http://schema.org",
     "@type": "CollectionPage",
     "mainEntity":
     {
         "@type": "ItemList",
         "itemListElement": [
         {
             "@type": "Product",
             "@id": "17-HMR-Pistol/search?Keywords=17%20HMR&Cats=978",
             "name": "TAURUS 17 TRACKER 17 HMR 6.5\" STAINLESS [ON SALE]",
             "image": ["https://p1.gunbroker.com/pics/859178000/859178890/pix140426005.jpg"],
             "description": "TAURUS 17 TRACKER 17 HMR 6.5\" STAINLESS [ON SALE] ",
             "sku": "2-170069",
             "mpn": " 2-170069",
             "manufacturer": "Taurus",
             "brand": "Taurus",
             "category": "17 HMR Pistol",
             "model": "Other Taurus",
             "weight": null,
             "gtin8": null,
             "gtin12": null,
             "gtin13": null,
             "gtin14": null,
             "productID": 859178890,
             "offers":
             {
                 "@type": "Offer",
                 "url": "https://www.gunbroker.com/item/859178890",
                 "priceCurrency": "USD",
                 "price": 438.98,
                 "priceValidUntil": "04/04/2020 16:05:18",
                 "itemCondition": "https://schema.org/NewCondition",
                 "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
                 "seller":
                 {
                     "@type": "Person",
                     "name": "XpressGuns"
                 }
             }
         }]
     }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi there, glad to have you here. You need to rework the question. It isn't clear what you need. More context is required. A schema doesn't have a markup. Here on SO people help when they see you tried. What did you try and where are yo stuck?

Comment: Sorry English isn't my first language. What I am trying to ask is I have an e-commerce website and I want to use schema on my items listed on the category page. I added product schema on each individual item page, yet it didn't show up for my category pages. My question is what type of schema I can use on my category pages is it CollectionPage or Offercatalog. I know Collection page is for creative work pages and Offercatalog is for products/services offered by the same provider. I hope this explains it more